# Is there a way to launch a VNC session from the commandline with MobaXTerm?

Tags: vnc, mobaxterm, gns3

I'm trying to set up MobaXTerm to automatically handle VNC connections from GNS3. GNS3 is just running commands to set up these sessions, for example, the default for connecting to telnet devices with MobaXTerm:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mobatek\MobaXterm Personal Edition\MobaXterm.exe" -newtab "telnet {host} {port}"`

This works great for telnet, but will not work if I simply replace `telnet` with `vnc`.

I first tried setting the command to

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mobatek\MobaXterm Personal Edition\MobaXterm.exe" -newtab "vnc {host}"`

(Where {host} would be replaced with the host IP)

And that brought up MobaXTerm with a window prompting a password with no hostname displayed. Entering any password into this dialog will display a message of  ["Error Incorrect Hostname"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwPFQ.png). It comes up with a title of "VNC Error", so I know at least it's attempting to make a connection, despite not getting a hostname.

My question is, is there any reference for this VNC command or any details on how to pass in a hostname and port?

Comment: As a note, I have successfully connected to this vnc server before using the actual interface of MobaXTerm, so I know the connection itself isn't the issue